# Python JSON New York Times API

Tags: python, json, api

Really new to Python and getting data from the web, so here it goes.

I have been able to pull data from the NYT api and parse the JSON output into a CSV file.  However, depending on my search, I may get the following error when I attempt to write a row to the CSV.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 20-21: character maps to

This [URL has the data](http://prototype.nytimes.com/gst/apitool/index.html?api_id=0&request_id=0&query=financial+aid&facets=&begin_date=20090901&end_date=20100221&fields=body,url,title,date,des_facet,desk_facet,byline&offset=1&rank=&resp_format=json&perform_request=Make+Request) that I am trying to parse into a CSV.  (I de-selected "Print pretty results")

I am pretty sure the error is occuring near title:"Spitzer......."

I have tried to search the web, but I can't seem to get an answer.  I don't know alot about encoding, but I am guessing the data I retrieve from the JSON records are encoded in some way.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Brock

Comment: should call it the JSON Blair API :)

Comment: Show your code plus the full traceback and FULL error message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your HTTP headers to see what char encoding they are using when returning the results.  My bet is that everything is encoded as utf-8 and when you try to write to CSV, you are implicitly encoding output as ascii.

The ' they are using is not in the ascii char set.  You can catch the UnicodeError exception.

Follow the [golden rules of encodings](http://automatist.net/techdaze/Unicode).

1. Decode early into unicode  (data.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
2. Use unicode internally.
3. Encode late - during output - data.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

You can probably set your CSV writer to use utf-8 encodings when writing.

Note: You should really see what encoding they are giving you before blindly using utf-8 for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Every piece of textual data is encoded. It's hard to tell what the problem is without any code, so the only advice I can give now is: Try decoding the response before parsing it ...

```
resp = do_request()
## look on the nyt site if they mention the encoding used and use it instead.
decoded = resp.decode('utf-8')
parsed = parse( decoded )
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be trying to decode '/' which is used whenever a slash is used.  This can be avoided by making using the string function.

```
str('http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2010\/02\/17\/business\/global\/17barclays.html')
'http:\\/\\/www.nytimes.com\\/2010\\/02\\/17\\/business\\/global\\/17barclays.html'
```

from there you can use replace.

```
str('http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2010\/02\/17\/business\/global\/17barclays.html').replace('\\', "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about nytimes API -- it does not provide you the full body text.